# How to programmatically select text in a TextInput component

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to programmatically highlight/select text that is inside a TextInput component?

Comment: Not without writing Native code. You can however select it all upon focus -> `selectTextOnFocus`

Comment: @G0dsquad Thanks, this works for my case.

Comment: Great, I'll add the answer.

Comment: I thought you meant select individual parts of the text. You can do it programmatically using the refs as shown below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually you can, by accessing textInput's method by refs.

`<TextInput ref={input => this.myInput = input} selectTextOnFocus style={{height: 100, width: 100}} defaultValue='Hey there' />`

and where you want to select all text programmatically you can

`this.myInput.focus()`

works on iOS, not sure about android.

---

---

Reference : http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/textinput.html#selectionstate

Comment: String refs are deprecated.

Comment: you can use a callback for that , edited. 
did it solve your problem?

Comment: Seems like this can also be done with the `autoFocus` and `selectTextOnFocus` props. Not sure if `autoFocus` was a thing in previous versions of RN when this question was asked tho.

Answer (score 38):

You can use `selectTextOnFocus` to achieve this. This will ensure that all text inside the `TextInput` is highlighted when the field is tapped into.

Comment: I found a way to do it in Javascript, but you have to focus the text first. Though this is preferred in my case.

Comment: Worked like a charm. This sholud be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a better way, but I found a workaround. The text has to be focused first. Here's an example

```
import React { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, TextInput, findNodeHandle } from 'react-native';
import TextInputState from 'react-native/lib/TextInputState';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
        <Button
          title="select text"
          onPress={() => {
            TextInputState.focusTextInput(findNodeHandle(this.inputRef))
          }}
        </
        <TextInput
          selectTextOnFocus
          ref={ref => this.inputRef = ref}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm here to share my findings. In a List, you might encounter that `selectTextOnFocus` is broken. In this case you can use this method `selection`. From React-Native I found this:

[image]

In my case I had trouble with the `selectTextOnFocus` prop in a list. So I had to add a `debounce` function to work with `selection` prop.

```
const [shouldSelect, setShouldSelect] = useState(undefined);
const onFocus = () =>{
    setShouldSelect({start:0, end:String(text).length});
}
const focus = useCallback(_.debounce(onFocus,500),[shouldSelect]);
  <TextInput
        selection={shouldSelect}
        onBlur={()=>setShouldSelect(undefined)}
        onFocus={()=>focus()}// this is important
        selectTextOnFocus
        ref={r=>onRef(r)}
        keyboardType={'number-pad'}
        autoCorrect={false}
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        returnKeyType={'done'}
        underlineColorIos={'transparent'}
        underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
        allowFontScaling={false}
        value={String(text)}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.inputRef.focus()` sets focus to the `TextInput` component, and then the flag you set in the attributes `selectTextOnFocus` does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Note: For those who wants to use `selectTextOnFocus` short answer. Actually, it works fine in IOS, but doesn't work in Android.

Thanks to Arnav Yagnik; Following is a similar approach in a functional component:

```
const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (inputRef.current) {
    console.log('focusing !');
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }
}, []);

return <TextInput
        multiline
        label="Amount"
        selectTextOnFocus
        placeholder="Write Count"
        value={stockCount.toString()}
      />
```