# How can I reliably select all text in an input field on focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, onclick

In essence, the basic stuff you find when looking for selecting contents on click works, but for me it doesn't work reliably. When I click the input element the first time, all text is selected as it should. If I click off of it, and then click it again, it selects the text, but then immediately de-selects it and shows a cursor where I clicked. This is a repeating pattern, i.e. it works once, then doesn't work once, etc..

I have tried preventing anything and everything with `preventDefault` and `stopImmediatePropagation`, I tried returning false in `onMouseUp`, but I can't get rid of this behavior. What's causing the deselection on the n*2-nd click, and how can I prevent it?

---

Edit in reply to comments:

I didn't include a snippet since, well, there is hardly anything to show:

```html
<input type="text" value="-:--" onFocus={((e) => e.target.select())} />
```

That's all, and that's causing me issues. In the meantime though, I started looking at alternative methods of handling this, and I stumbled into something that may be relevant: the text doesn't get de-selected if I click off of the input window. If I click on the input and call `document.getSelection().toString()` in the console, it prints `-:--` as expected. However, if I then click somewhere else on the page, which deselects the input field, and call `document.getSelection().toString()` again, it still prints `-:--`. This gave me enough info to figure out what the issue is and how to fix it, so I'll add my own answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718405/how-to-programmatically-select-text-in-a-textinput-component

Comment: @ShivamJha - That question is about React Native.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh no, my bad, i was opening two tabs, one for `RN` n one for `react`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-vanilla-js-or-jquery

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**
Either call `document.getSelection().empty()` in `onBlur`/`onFocusOut`, or make sure you don't have `user-select: none` set on everything.

**Explanation**
It turns out the issues I was having were caused by having `user-select: none` set on the entire `body`, which prevented the actual deselection of the text in the input field. Although the text did look like it was deselected (the blue highlighting disappeared), calling `document.getSelection().toString()` showed that the text was still selected.

Since setting `user-select: none` on the body is pretty agressive, I suspect most people would recommend you don't do that, and be more specific. If you still want to keep it on the body though, calling `document.getSelection().empty()` (which deselects your selection) in an `onBlur`/`onFocusOut` event also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)"
```